# JavaScript with PHP MySQLi

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a kind of "Popup"-Window to show the user which I've clicked.

HTML-Code:

```
<div onclick="showUser(ID)" id="userBox"><?php echo $username; ?></div>
```

The **showUser(ID)** should show the window at the top with the user-infos. **ID** is the ID of the user from the database.

JS-Code:

```
function showUser(ID???) {
 document.getElementById('userShowBox').style.display ='block';
}
```

User info show-box:

```
<div id="userShowBox">
 <?php $showuserinfo->mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '??'"); ?>
</div>
```

I've no idea how to connect the js-code with php-codes, for to show then the user-infos in the box.

Comment: Firstly: having DB related PHP code mixed in with markup is bad practice. Secondly: [RTM: `json_encode` is what you want](http://www.php.net/json_encode)

Comment: You cannot mix PHP and javascript like they're equal. You can "insert" PHP in javascript that will be interpreted once it's send to the browser (browsers don't understand PHP). If you want to send something from javascript to PHP and get an answer, you require something like AJAX. See for information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) (it contains also an example).

Answer (score 0):

To add more information for your comprehension, JS is executed as client-side and PHP is executed as server-side, you can't directly "connect" PHP and JS, I see two different way to do what you want

1. Load the user ID (with a PHP mysqli query) when the page is loaded and hide the ID to wait for user input

HTML

```
<div onclick="showUser()" id="userBox" style="display:none"><?php /* mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '??'")*/ ?></div>
```

JS

```
function showUser() {
 document.getElementById('userShowBox').style.display ='block';
}
```

2. Use a AJAX call to dynamically retrieve the use ID when user click your element, consider using a library such as jQuery to ease the process

HTML

```
<div onclick="showUser(<?php echo $username?>)" id="userBox"></div>
```

JS

```
function showUser(userName) {
$.ajax({
   url : 'getID.php',
   type : 'GET',
   data : "username="+userName,
   dataType : 'html', // On désire recevoir du HTML
   success : function(data, statut)
   {
       document.getElementById('userShowBox').html(data);
   }
});

}
```

getID.php

```
/* username is in $_GET['username'] */
mysqli_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = '??'");
......

/* this will 'return' userid to the ajax call */
echo $userID;
```